# Word for 'Unafraid to Question Authority' with Positive Connotations

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe a person that is unafraid to question authority with a **positive** connotation? I feel that 'rebel' has too much of a negative connotation for the context that I'm using it in, and iconoclast doesn't fit too well.

I need it to be a one word noun, as in:

> At heart, I am a ____.

Comment: ***Speaks truth to power***.

Comment: That is the message that I'm going for, but I need it to be a one word noun, as in: "At heart, I am a ____".

Comment: Eh, maybe an ***iconoclast**. I doubt you’ll find a single noun that is purely positive; any such nouns are likely to have negative glosses as well. By try using *iconoclast* as the root to your thesaurus search.

Comment: Perhaps [maverick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maverick) - MW gives one definition as "an independent individual who does not go along with a group or party", which might just fit here. Of course, the word only has a positive connotation if you're not the authority being questioned or defied, which is why this is only a "might just fit".

Comment: Normally I would say *critical thinker*.  One of my children went to an alternative school that trained the students to be critical thinkers.  But that's two words.

Comment: The one word form is 'critic' and that can be a neutral/ positive word (think literary critic, drama critic, social critic etc -- one who thinks about those things critically) : *"at heart I am a critic."*  I also just suggested in my own answer the one-word form "freethinker" that has the essential meaning of "critical thinker" @aparente001.

Answer (score 2):

The 'positive' word that came to mind is **freethinker** which I found defined as

> a person who forms opinions on the basis of reason, independent of authority or tradition [...]

at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/freethinker

Collins Dictionary gives a very similar definition:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freethinker

"Independent of authority" is the part that fits your case.

Free thinking has historically been considered a defiance of authority in itself because the independence of the mind is the first step towards other forms of independence. Moreover a freethinker encourages others (who come into contact with him) to reject 'received wisdom' and  think critically for themselves, which is considered a direct challenge to traditional forms of authority.

> At heart, I am a ***freethinker.***

(Oh yes I am, even though I don't go and deliberately challenge anybody's authority!)

---

Note: the exhaustive list of synonyms of 'rebel' at http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rebel does not seem to contain a single word whose meaning is commonly understood in a 'positive sense.' That tells you that society does not like a person or group that questions authority. In the context of armed resistance or revolution [I have heard it said that](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22One+man%27s+rebel+is+another+man%27s+freedom-fighter%22+-terrorist&oq=%22One+man%27s+rebel+is+another+man%27s+freedom-fighter%22+-terrorist&gs_l=)

> One man's rebel is another man's freedom-fighter.